# Error when Connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was working with an instance of SQL Server 2012, but after updating my Avast (anti-virus)  I can't connect to that instance anymore and I have this error message:

> TITLE: Registered Servers
>
> Failed to connect to server . (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Aucune connexion n’a pu être
>   établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée.) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 10061) Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car
>   l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée BUTTONS: OK "

I just want to be precise that I have allowed all TCP/IP connection rules from my firewall system and each time I try to start the server from the SQL Server Management Studio it doesn't work :(

What should I do ?

Answer (score 11):

Check is `SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)` service is running or not.

> RightClick on MYComputer->Manage->Service and
>   Application->Services->SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)

Right Click on it and start it, then try to connect Sql Server.

Comment: that's the fist thing I did but it's not working !! "each time I try to start the server from the SQL Server Manager it doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

services.msc just use this commend in cmd, then find out (sql server) then start it simply , will work

Comment: It would be better to give a practical example. It would be much more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I also experience the same issue and this was i did to resolve the issue

. i went to my computer 
. lunch sql server manager
. right-click on (MSSQLSERVER)
. and click on propertiesand check buit-in-account radio button
. select network service from the drop down and press apply and ok

That was all. Hope this work